# My List that auto calculates prices by amount of product wont accept amount of product

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a list where u can put in the amount of product u want and press a button and the Sum of all the products will be calculated, i am having trouble with the function to get the ammount for each product. I always get the error message when trying the button: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
let WaschlotionAmount;
let HaarshampooAmont;
let BodylotionAmount;
let WundschutzcremeAmount;
let DeosprayAmount;
let ZahncremeAmount;
let ZahnbuersteAmount;
let ZahnspuellbecherAmount;
let ZahnhaftcremeAmount;
let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount;
let RasierklingenAmount;
let RasiererMitKlingenAmount;
let RasierschaumAmount;
let EinwegrasiererAmount;

let Sum;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
      <th>Menge</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Waschlotion</td>
      <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haarshampoo</td>
      <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bodylotion</td>
      <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
      <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deospray</td>
     <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Zahnbürste</td>
   <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
  <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="Rasierschaum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><p id="Sum"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="SetAmount()">Try me</button>
</body>
<script>
var Waschlotion = 1.30;
var Haarshampoo = 1.50;
var Bodylotion = 3;
var Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
var Deospray = 1.80;
var Zahncreme = 3.20;
var Zahnbuerste = 1;
var Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
var Zahnhaftcreme = 1.50;
var Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
var Rasierklingen = 2.49;
var RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
var Rasierschaum = 1.20;
var Einwegrasierer = 2.40;



function SetAmount() {
  let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
  let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
  let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
  let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
  let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
  let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
  let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
  let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
  let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
  let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
  let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
  let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
}

function Calculate() {
  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = Sum;
}
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: "RasierschaumAmount" this element is not exists in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change id of **Rasierschaum** to **RasierschaumAmount**. It will work!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
          <th>Menge</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Waschlotion</td>
          <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haarshampoo</td>
          <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bodylotion</td>
          <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
          <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Deospray</td>
         <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Zahncreme</td>
        <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Zahnbürste</td>
       <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
      <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
        <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
        <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rasierklingen</td>
        <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
        <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rasierschaum</td>
        <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
        <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
        <td><p id="Sum"></p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="SetAmount()">Try me</button>
    </body>
    <script>
    let Waschlotion = 1.30;
    let Haarshampoo = 1.50;
    let Bodylotion = 3;
    let Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
    let Deospray = 1.80;
    let Zahncreme = 3.20;
    let Zahnbuerste = 1;
    let Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
    let Zahnhaftcreme = 1.50;
    let Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
    let Rasierklingen = 2.49;
    let RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
    let Rasierschaum = 1.20;
    let Einwegrasierer = 2.40;



    function SetAmount() {
      let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
      let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
      let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
      let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
      let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
      let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
      let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
      let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
      let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
      let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
      let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
      let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
      let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
      let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
    }

    function Calculate() {
      document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = Sum;
    }
     </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: omg im such an idiot XD thx man it worked <3

Comment: If that helps you! It's okay...

Answer (score 1):

Do not re-declare variable in `SetAmount` with `let`. It shadows the global variable.

Also, you declared your variables twice - once at beginning with `let`, once in the middle with `var`.

Comment: So i should just drop the let in the function like this ? WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;

Comment: If you want to set a value at an outter scope, then you should not re-declare it in an inner scope.

Answer (score 0):

```html
function SetAmount() {
   WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
   HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
   BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
   WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
   DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
   ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
   ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
   ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
   ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
   ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
   RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
   RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
   RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
   EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
}
```

in you function you create again a variable which is only available in that function